# Pg_restore create index duplicate

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

Using pg_restore with 8 jobs for the database when starting to create the indexes these are being executed in duplicate as you can see they are different PID for each CREATE INDEX

Command used:
pg_restore -v --jobs=8 --dbname=DB_TEST_1804 -U postgres -c /mnt/pgbackup/BACKUP/PRODUCTION_23.dump

[image: query_pg_stat_activity]

At first, to correct it would be to restore the database using only 2 jobs, but the machine has 32 cores and I want to use the maximum resources available

Comment: Looks like a single index, created by several parallel processes. Not multiple indexes

Answer (score 0):

That is perfectly normal. It looks like you have set `max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 5`, so that six processes are working on a single `CREATE INDEX` statement. With 8 parallel processes, you could end up with as many as 48 processes working in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support.
This multiple index creation will effectively create the same index several times, I mean to rewrite the same index several times, consuming processing?
Or does the first process create 1 index lock the table, causing the other processes to be stuck waiting for this conclusion, and as soon as the first process completes, the others will give an error because there is already an index with the same name?

Comment: No. The processes cooperate to create a single index. Each does part of the work.